# unable to display images in a list after uploading using the user id

Tags: javascript, php, html

im trying to display images in a list after uploading, i want php to fetch the images using the 'user_id' from the database.

here's my php code

```
<div class="container-two">
    <?php
        $image = "";
        $caption = "";
        if ("POST" == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
            $caption = $_POST['Caption'];
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Y1qSYlz1iTNBMCfY","schedios");
            $query = "SELECT Img_dir FROM images WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $row = $result->mysqli_fetch_assoc();
            $image = $row['Img_dir'];
        }


    ?>

<div>
    <?php
            $array = array();

            while ($row =   mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {

            $array['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
            echo "<ul><li ><img src='$image' ></li></ul>";}

    ?>
</div>
```

i have a table of designers, so this is the dashboard, where the user can upload images and display , thanks in advance to help.

Comment: where is image_path? in src before the $image

Comment: @M.Hemant the image is in the database not folder

Comment: @sureshbambhaniya what do you mean projection? im using $query to check the coloumn Img_dir with the  session id

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to fetch $query ?

```
$row =   mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)
```

You should to do the same with $result if i'm getting you right

```
 while ($row =   mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
        $image = $row['Img_dir']; // maybe add $row['Img_name'] if exist in your database
       // $array['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];// you already know userid from $_SESSION, right ?
        echo "<ul><li ><img src='$image' ></li></ul>";}
```

Comment: the image is in the database, im fetching $result putting it into $row then $row into $image...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, you are trying to echo image dir in  li only, so try to save full image path in database while uploading, let me give you, sample code to give an idea.

---

1. Receive image uploaded by user from form:

   ```
          // image file directory
          $target = "images/".basename($image);

           $sql = "INSERT INTO images (user_id,image) 
                       VALUES 
                      ('".$_SESSION['user_id']."','$image')";
          // execute query
          mysqli_query($con, $sql);

         if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
           $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
          }else{
           $msg = "Failed to upload image";
        }
     }
     $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE user_id = 
              '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ");
     ?>
   ```

---

2.Display images back to user on unordered list:

```
<div id="content">
  <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<div id='img_div'>";
        echo "<ul><li>img src='images/".$row['image']."' /><li></ul>";
      echo "</div>";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: how about fetching from the database? coz the image is stored in the column Img_dir

Comment: in my case image is saved in folder on web server, then its corresponding url is kept database, it is the best practice to do it like that.